# Online vs Offline data augmentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I can do online or "on the fly" [Image augmentation layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/) or using [Image  Data Generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Or I can do augmentation and the save the relevant images on hard disk.

What is the **advantages / disadvantages** of each approach ?

I don't consider the storage issue.

Also offline approach can provide a "double check" option to ensure, that all augmentation are done is it was planned.

Answer (score 1):

May be check out this NVIDIA post:

https://docs.nvidia.com/tao/tao-toolkit/text/offline_data_augmentation.html

"Online augmentation in the training data loader is a good way to increase the variation in the dataset. However, the augmented data is generated randomly based on the distribution the data loader follows when sampling the data. In order to achieve good accuracy, the model may need to be trained for a long time.  In order to circumvent this and generate a dataset with the required augmentations (*Offline augmentation can be used*). Offline augmentation can dramatically increase the size of the dataset when collecting and labeling data is expensive or not possible."

I think, your last sentence is right on point.